# how to read image saved on s3 bucket using Angular 12?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I am able to save a jpeg image on s3 bucket. Now i want to view the saved image in Angular application for verification. I am using this code.

```
const params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: `${folderName}/${fileName}`
};
this.bucket.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); 
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

this works but returns a response like this

[image]

How can I convert this Body to an image to show in UI?

Comment: Is your S3 bucket public?

Comment: No, somehow I am able to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was difficult to convert, I retrieved the image from s3 url path

```
 const params = {
  Bucket: bucketName,
  Key: `${folderName}/${fileName}`
 };
 this.bucket.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
   console.error(err); 
  } else {
  data.Contents.map((photo) => {
      var photoKey = photo.Key;
      var photoUrl = bucketUrl + (photoKey);
      // this photoUrl is used in image src in HTML file
      // make sure while uploading an image it should be public-read
      
    });
  }
 });
```

Maybe this solution can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for someone:

```
this.userImage = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.Body.toString('base64');
```